# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client on res.send()

Tags: node.js, express

coders. I try to implement file upload through Multer. I however get an error trying to catch errors to send to the frontend.
I've tried going through the documentation and the various questions already asked here on Stackoverflow but my understanding of English seems to be so low. `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`  is my error. I can't find where the headers were sent, or where the process ended. May someone with a better understanding help me out. Here is my code. It happens after the `db.query()`

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "./routes/files");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + "-" + file.originalname);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage }).fields([
  { name: "file", maxCount: 1 },
  { name: "school_id", maxCount: 1 },
]);

router.post("/upload/students", (req, res) => {
  try {
    upload(req, res, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.json({ msg: err.message });
      } else {
        const filePath = req.files["file"][0].path; //req.file.path;
        const workbook = xlsx.readFile(filePath);
        const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];

        const rows = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);

        const school_id = req.body.school_id;
        console.log("SchoolId ", school_id);

        rows.forEach((row) => {
          const student_id = row.student_id;
          const klass_id = row.klass;
          const stream_id = row.stream;
          const name = row.name;
          const year = row.year;

          db.query(
            "INSERT INTO student(graduated, prefect, school_id,\
               name, student_id, klass_id, stream_id, year)\
            VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8 )",
            [0, 0, school_id, name, student_id, klass_id, stream_id, year],
            (err) => {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                // res.json({ msg: err.message });
              } else {
                console.log("Successfull");
                // res.json({ success: "Students Uploaded Successfully" });
              }
            }
          );
        });
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ msg: err.message });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: This isn't very clear. Where is your _success_ response? You're also performing async operations in a loop. If you try and send a response within that loop (like with the commented-out code), it will cause the error you're seeing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

Answer (score 0):

Well you should wrap your async code inside a promise, then after promise you can res.send your success.

Comment: Looks like OP is using a DB library that doesn't support promises (or they are using the callback version even if it does)

Comment: well he can still wrap all of the loop inside a async await function.

Comment: Not really. Promisifying a callback API is a little more complex than that

Answer (score -1):

An answer was posted that has since been deleted. Adding return solved it

```
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.json({ msg: err.message });
    **return**
```

Comment: There is no way, given the code in your question that this would solve the problem you describe

Comment: I realized that it's actually not yet working. But you're not providing a solution, why?? I'm using postgres

Comment: Why? Because I asked you a bunch of clarifying questions in the comments above and you haven't answered them or provided details

Comment: Success response is commented out, res.json({ success: "Students Uploaded Successfully" });